# Pushing Symbology and Labeling from Layer Properties in QGIS to features on Map and TOC with Python

Tags: pyqgis, labeling, symbology

I'm using QGIS 3.20.3-Odense.

I have written a script that changes the symbology and labeling of layers in QGIS. Everything looks great when I double click on layers in the TOC to view the Symbology and Label tabs but when I click on an individual feature in the TOC it doesn't match up with what is in the symbology pane. Also, when I am panning around the map I notice that features aren't labeled when they should be. Both problems are alleviated if I double click on each layer press "Okay" but I don't want to have to do this for every layer for the hundreds of maps I am working with.
I have tried `iface.mapCanvas().redrawAllLayers()`, `layer.triggerRepaint()`, `layer.dataProvider().forceReload()` but nothing seems to work. I have inserted some images below to illustrate what is happening.

This image shows what it looks like when I double click on the layer, then double click on a feature in the Symbology tab:
[image]

This image shows what it looks like when I double click directly on the same feature from the TOC:
[image]

Here is my script:

```
#----Change this variable manually
mapScale = 24000

if mapScale == 24000:
    pointSize = 65
    lineWidth = 5
    labelTextSize = 100
    labelOffset = 50
    linelabelOffset = 25
elif mapScale == 31680:
    pointSize = 70
    lineWidth = 7
    labelTextSize = 105
    labelOffset = 55
    linelabelOffset = 30
elif mapScale == 48000:
    pointSize = 75
    lineWidth = 10
    labelTextSize = 115
    labelOffset = 85
    linelabelOffset = 35
elif mapScale == 62500:
    pointSize = 80
    lineWidth = 13
    labelTextSize = 125
    labelOffset = 90
    linelabelOffset = 50
elif mapScale == 63360:
    pointSize = 80
    lineWidth = 13
    labelTextSize = 125
    labelOffset = 90
    linelabelOffset = 50
elif mapScale == 100000:
    pointSize = 90
    lineWidth = 21
    labelTextSize = 140
    labelOffset = 150
    linelabelOffset = 75
elif mapScale == 125000:
    pointSize = 100
    lineWidth = 26
    labelTextSize = 150
    labelOffset = 175
    linelabelOffset = 90
elif mapScale == 250000:
    pointSize = 150
    lineWidth = 52
    labelTextSize = 350
    labelOffset = 200
    linelabelOffset = 150
else:
    pointSize = 65
    lineWidth = 5
    labelTextSize = 100
    labelOffset = 25
    linelabelOffset = 25

from random import randrange
layers = iface.mapCanvas().layers()
mapLayers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayers()
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
expression = "Symbology = '31.10'"
for layer in layers:
    concatLayer = layer.name().split('_',1)[1]
    renderer = layer.renderer()
    if renderer.type() == 'RuleRenderer':
        root_rule = renderer.rootRule()
        rule_list = root_rule.children()
        for rule in rule_list:
            rule.symbol().setOutputUnit(1)
        if concatLayer == 'Geologic_Cross_Section_Lines':
            rule.setFilterExpression(expression)
        if layer.fields().indexFromName("Label") == -1:
            next
        else:
            labelSettings = QgsPalLayerSettings()
            text_format = QgsTextFormat()
            text_format.setFont(QFont("Arial", labelTextSize))
            text_format.setSize(labelTextSize)
            text_format.setSizeUnit(1)
            if "Folds" in layer.name():
                text_format.setColor(QColor('magenta'))
            labelSettings.setFormat(text_format)
            labelSettings.fieldName = "Label"
            if layer.geometryType() == 0: # point features
                labelSettings.placement = 1
                labelSettings.quadOffset = 4
                labelSettings.xOffset = labelOffset
                labelSettings.yOffset = labelOffset
                labelSettings.offsetUnits = 1
            elif layer.geometryType() == 1: #line features
                labelSettings.placement = 1
                labelSettings.dist = linelabelOffset
                labelSettings.distUnits = 1
            elif layer.geometryType() == 2: #polygon features
                labelSettings.centroidInside = True
            layer.setLabeling(QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling(labelSettings))
            layer.setLabelsEnabled(True)
        if layer.geometryType() == 1:
            if layer.fields().indexFromName("Positional_Accuracy") == -1:
                next
            else:
                for feature in layer.getFeatures():
                    idx = layer.fields().indexFromName('Positional_Accuracy')
                    if feature.attributes()[idx] == 'queried' or feature.attributes()[idx] == 'gradational'\
                    or feature.attributes()[idx] == 'concealed and queried'\
                    or feature.attributes()[idx] == 'inferred and queried'\
                    or feature.attributes()[idx] == 'approximate and queried':
                        if "Modified" not in layer.name():
                            newName = layer.name() + "_(Modified_Symbology)"
                            layer.setName(newName)
                        break
                    else:
                        next
        

    else:
        fni = layer.dataProvider().fieldNameIndex("Feature_Type")
        unique_values = layer.dataProvider().uniqueValues(fni)
        categories = []
        for unique_value in unique_values:
            symbol = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(layer.geometryType())
            symbol.setOutputUnit(1)
            if layer.geometryType() == 0: # point features
                symbol.setSize(pointSize)
            elif layer.geometryType() ==1: # line features
                symbol.setWidth(lineWidth)
            layer_style = {}
            layer_style['color'] = '%d, %d, %d' % (randrange(0,256), randrange(0,256), randrange(0,256))
            layer_style['outline'] = '#000000'
            symbol_layer = QgsSimpleFillSymbolLayer.create(layer_style)
            if symbol_layer is not None:
                symbol.changeSymbolLayer(0, symbol_layer)
            category = QgsRendererCategory(unique_value, symbol, str(unique_value))
            categories.append(category)
        renderer = QgsCategorizedSymbolRenderer('Feature_Type', categories)
        if renderer is not None:
            layer.setRenderer(renderer)
        layer.triggerRepaint()
        if layer.fields().indexFromName("Label") == -1:
            next
        else:
            labelSettings = QgsPalLayerSettings()
            text_format = QgsTextFormat()
            text_format.setFont(QFont("Arial", labelTextSize))
            text_format.setSize(labelTextSize)
            text_format.setSizeUnit(QgsUnitTypes.RenderMapUnits)
            labelSettings.setFormat(text_format)
            labelSettings.fieldName = "Label"
            if layer.geometryType() == 0:
                labelSettings.placement = 1
                labelSettings.quadOffset = 4
                labelSettings.xOffset = labelOffset
                labelSettings.yOffset = labelOffset
                labelSettings.offsetUnits = 1
            layer.setLabeling(QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling(labelSettings))
            layer.setLabelsEnabled(True)
        if "Incomplete" not in layer.name():
            newName = layer.name() + "_(Incomplete_Symbology)"
            layer.setName(newName)
            
for layer in layers:
    print(layer.name())
    layer.dataProvider().forceReload()
    layer.triggerRepaint()
iface.mapCanvas().redrawAllLayers()
```